# could able to run demo sound classification application in openvino

Tags: python, openvino

To run sound classication demo in openvino,
I have followed below steps:

1. `cd /opt/intel/openvino_2021/install_dependencies`
2. `sudo -E ./install_openvino_dependencies.sh`
3. for env setting: `source /opt/intel/openvino_2021/bin/setupvars.sh`
4. `cd /opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites`
5. `sudo ./install_prerequisites.sh`
6. `git clone https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo.git`.
   Then I placed the cloned repo in the `deployment_tools` directory.
7. `sudo python3 /opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/downloader/downloader.py --name aclnet`
8. `sudo python3 /opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/downloader/converter.py --name aclnet`

Here I got error:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.4) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "

Unable to locate Model Optimizer. Use --mo or run setupvars.sh/setupvars.bat from the OpenVINO toolkit.
```

Here aclent model downloaded and gives .onnx in public folder. now how to convert .onnx file to ir format(xml and bin format)?

I followed below coomand too but still I get same error

```
sudo python3 ./mo.py --input_model ~/public/aclnet/aclnet_des_53.onnx --output_dir ~/public/aclnet
```

https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_demos_sound_classification_demo_python.html

Please can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

This error happened because the script attempts to locate Model Optimizer using the environment variables set by the OpenVINO™ toolkit's setupvars.sh script. You can override this heuristic with the --mo option:

*python3 converter.py --mo my/openvino/path/model_optimizer/mo.py --name aclnet*